# Why it's showing 'ValueError' even though there are no NaN, infinity or large values?

Tags: python, pandas

I replaced all inf values with nan values. Then, all dropped rows with nan values.
I also changed the dtype to float32.

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
df = df.dropna()
```

[image]

```
X = df.iloc[:,:-1].astype('float32')
y = df.iloc[:,-1].astype('float32')

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
k=10
kf = KFold(n_splits=k, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
acc_score = []

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.reindex(index = train_index), X.reindex(index = test_index)
    y_train, y_test = y.reindex(index = train_index), y.reindex(index = test_index)
    reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = reg.predict(X_test)
    acc_score.append(accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))
```

[image]

Comment: Try moving the .astype('float32') before dropping the Nulls

Comment: try `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before definine `X` and `y`. Or use `X.iloc[train_index]` inside the `for` loop. Also, you may want to define `reg` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

refer to the documentation [DataFrame.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html?highlight=reindex#pandas.DataFrame.reindex)

> Conform Series/DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic.
>
> Places NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index. A
> new object is produced unless the new index is equivalent to the
> current one and copy=False.

your use of reindex in creating X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test is introducing null values